# Wait for resource to complete

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a recipe that looks similar to this:

```
...
custom_resource1 "example" do
  writing stuff to a file
end
log 'File found!' do
  message "Found it
  level :info
  notifies :run, 'custom_resource2[example]', :immediately
  only_if { ::File.exists?(file) }
end
...
```

`custom_resource1` is a big resource with other resources inside, and takes some time to complete (iterates over some `data_bags` and writes to a file).

Sometimes, I see that `custom_resource1` fails during a chef run, but still `custom_resource2` is triggered before the recipe fails.

Is there any way to ensure that `custom_resource1` either failed or completed before moving on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also thought it was strange, because the log statement was never printed out, even though custom_resource2 were triggered by the notify. The soloution was to remove the log statement and instead add:

`custom_resource2 "example" do
  do stuff
  only_if { ::File.exists?(file) }
end`

Guess it has something to do with the different chef phases

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible, Chef uses an entirely blocking execution model (other than the two-pass loading system). The full action method for each resource is run in order with no concurrency. You would have to post more code to isolate the actual problem.